# Insert blank line in doxygen code fragment

Tags: python, doxygen

In the fragment 
@code
some code
@endcode

How do I get a closing blank line in the output?

Comment: please consider accepting answers in your previous questions before asking a new one

Comment: That was a mistake on me.. Will do it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a simple fix:

### \htmlonly

### \endhtmlonly

Seem to to the job of inserting a single blank line in doxygen generated page.